# Is it possible to override the default URL for Servicestack RegistrationFeature?

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to override the default URL for Servicestack RegistrationFeature?

I would like to use something other than /register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [committed a fix](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f7bf7318d5090cf4ab3d0fc8567ae767f2b409df) so in the next release (v3.9.55+) you can configure it with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature { AtRestPath = "/myregisterpath" });
```

Comment: Very quick answer, sure to be useful for others.  In the end I needed to implement a custom Plugin because I need to customise the response.